# How to send base64 in fromdata to nodejs server from ionic or angular?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, file-upload, base64

[image: corroupted file saved][image: file comes on backend like this object][Backend save file on file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kt0a.png)    pickImage(sourceType) {
        const options: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          sourceType: sourceType,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
          correctOrientation: true,
        };
        // this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

```
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      (imageData) => {


        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', imageData);
        let newName = this.randomString(6) + new Date().getTime() + "." + file.type;

        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));

 this.http.post("//localhost:3000/api/v1/Admin/saveAllImages", formData)
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                // loading.dismiss();
            })
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
            if (res['success']) {
                this.presentToast('File upload complete.')
            } else {
                this.presentToast('File upload failed.')
            }
        });
    };

}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: imageData = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+imageData;

  
  
              let formData = new FormData();
             
              formData.append('file', imageData) //append base64 file


 // send to api post call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let formData = new FormData();
let blob = this.DataURIToBlob(this.imageData);
formData.append('file', blob)


DataURIToBlob(dataURI: string) {
        const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
        const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
        const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

        const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
        for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)

        return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString })
      }
```

Comment: it's giving me file data on my nodejs server but when I am going to save the file , corrupted file saved , I have attached screen above

Comment: can't see screen

Comment: and what is imageData?

Comment: file comes to the backend and when I save the file, file show me corrupted

Comment: see screen in the above question description

Comment: imageData is basically the base64 format long string

Comment: i was also tried DataURIToBlob() function , its perfectly wrap image to formdata , its also comes on the backend , as shown in the question description image , but file saved "corruptly", the issue is only this , shown as above image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214473/discussion-between-shashwat-gupta-and-aakash-garg).